# How does Apple's free apps program work?

Tags: mac-appstore, ios-appstore, iwork, ilife

Apple recently announced that iLife and iWork suites are free with new Macs and iOS devices, but how does it work? Is it preinstalled? What happens if I wipe out the system—will it still be free in the App Store? Does it associate the apps with purchases on a single Apple ID?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever buying anything from Apple in the recent past that came with software, it's been linked to my Apple ID, so perpetually available in the App Store.

Eg. buying a Macbook just as Mountain Lion came out, it shipped without it, but was available for free from the store with it when I logged in with my Apple ID.